# Access to login passwords using preserve log

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, password-encryption, google-signin

While logging on to services of Gmail, Facebook and other sites also, if on performing inspect element and checking the "Preserve Log" box, the password is clearly visible without any encryption in one of the files being sent to the server.
[image: While logging into Gmail]

The same doesn't happen when logging into Yahoomail
[image: When logging into YahooMail]

Why exactly is this occurring? Is it some bug or some programming error? The data being sent to the server is without any encryption. Using tools like WireShark, the passwords can easily be sniffed.

Answer (score 1):

Why, yes, indeed, passwords that you type into a form and then submit that form to the server are in plaintext. By necessity. Because the server needs the plaintext password to authenticate you. Hopefully the *connection* this plaintext is sent across is HTTPS encrypted, which means no third party can intercept the traffic and see the plaintext. Your browser happens to be able to display the plaintext for you, since, well, it's the originator of the data and a peer in the HTTPS connection.

I don't know what specifically you're doing with Yahoo, but at some point it too will have to send the password to the server in some form or another.

Comment: With Yahoo and other services also, the password being sent to the network is encrypted. Some also use JavaScript to encrypt the password that is being sent.

Comment: Encrypting the password with Javascript is mostly pointless really. Should someone capture the data being sent from your browser to the server... then the Javascript-encrypted password *is your password*. Maybe the plaintext password is not recoverable, but it's still possible to login with that encrypted password and a replay attack. ***HTTPS*** is the only useful transport encryption on the web, and a well implemented HTTPS connection is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: If not HTTPS and JavaScript, what is Yahoo using then?

Comment: They're also submitting the password in plaintext, but they're making a separate request for it. Have a closer look at the ongoing requests.